# Drupal 6 & Custom query sanitization

Tags: 6, database

Reading through Drupal 6 docs, it appears that `db_query` and `db_query_range` take the entire query.

This is different from Drupal 7, which can separately take user input as an argument, effectively sanitizing it.

What is the proper way to deal with custom queries, that contain unsafe input in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal 6 version of [db_query](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_query/6) supports placeholders.  The best explantion of these is probably the [Writing secure code](http://drupal.org/writing-secure-code) article.

A (contrived) example would be

```
$query = "
  SELECT node.nid FROM {node} node
  INNER JOIN {content_type_foo} content_type_foo ON content_type_foo.nid = node.nid
  WHERE content_type_foo.field_foo_value = '%s'
";

$foo = $_GET["foo"];    
$nid = db_result(db_query($query, $foo));
```

The referenced article also shows how to use placeholder arrays for handling a variable number of arguments, like for `WHERE IN` queries.

The second edition of [Pro Drupal Development](http://www.drupalbook.com/), which covers Drupal 6, is also a good reference for using the database abstraction later.